# Fake method of class under test

Tags: mocking, phpunit

for example I have a class

```php
class Foo {

  protected $settingUsedInloadSettings;
  protected $settings;

  public function __construct($param) {
    $this->$settingUsedInloadSettings = $param;
    $this->loadSettings();
    //do other initial stuff
  }

  protected function loadSettings() {
    $this->settings['settingToFake'] = 'some data using' 
      . $this->$settingUsedInloadSettings
      . 'and stuff from database and/or filesystem';
  }

  public function functionUnderTest() {
    //do api-calls with $this->settings['settingToFake']
  }

}
```

and a working test with valid data in `$this->settings['settingToFake']`

```php
class FooTest extends TestCase {

  public function testFunctionToTest(){

    $classUnderTest = new Foo('settingUsedInloadSettings');

    $actual = $classUnderTest->functionUnderTest();
    $expected = ['expectedValue'];
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
  }

}
```

now I want `loadSettings()` to set Invalid data to `$this->settings['settingToFake']` in a second test, to get another response from the api called in `functionUnderTest()`

```php
public function testFunctionToTest(){

  //fake / mock / stub loadSettings() some how

  $classUnderTest = new Foo('settingUsedInloadSettings');

  $actual = $classUnderTest->functionUnderTest();
  $expected = ['expectedValue'];
  $this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: In this particular case I load a file in `loadSettings()` from a production directory but for the second test, want to load a "fake-file" from my fixtures directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by overriding the `loadSettings` method in an anonymous class in your test:

```
public function testFunctionToTest()
{
    $classUnderTest = new class('settingUsedInloadSettings') extends Foo {
        protected function loadSettings()
        {
           $this->settings['settingToFake'] = 'invalid value';
        }
    };

    // ...
}
```